# How to fix Toolbar and Sidebar without fixing top value?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Top `Toolbar` which is fixed and a `Sidebar` which is also fixed. I want to put `Sidebar` just under the `Toolbar` but don't want to put any `top` value or `margin-top`. Is it possible? With `top` value I have done this with Bootstrap-4.

```
<!-- Sidebar  -->
 <nav id="sidebar" class="sticky-top sticky-offset">
    -----------------
 </nav>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top">
   -------------
</nav>

<style>
.sticky-offset {
    top: 56px!important;
}
</style>
```

I don't want to use `top`

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate, why you do not want to put any `top` properties for your containers?
What you want is easily achievable if you have your `Sidebar` container **inside** `Toolbar` container. In that case, you can have `Toolbar` with `position: fixed;` and `Sidebar` with `position: absolute;`:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <span>Toolbar</span>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <span>Sidebar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

Check out this Fiddle demo, maybe it will put you on track:
https://jsfiddle.net/giiintas/xLjvg17e/12/